# Move a object by flicking

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I can move the box by touching it and dragging it along the x-axis, but i like to be able to flick it from one side to the other. is there a simple solution to do this?

```
local box = display.newRect( 0, 0, 50, 50) 
box:setFillColor( math.random(0,255), math.random(0,255), math.random(0,255) )
physics.addBody( box, { density=3.0, friction=0.5 } )
box.gravityScale = 0.0 

function box:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
    self.markX = self.x    
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
    local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX        
    self.x = x    
    end
    return true
end
box:addEventListener( "touch", box )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `transition.to`, but you'll have to decide by how much to move. I'll assume you want to move it all the way to other side:

```
function box:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        self.markX = self.x   

    elseif event.phase == "end" then
        local targetX = 0 -- if flick left
        if event.x > self.markX then -- flick right
            targetX = display.contentWidth - self.width
        end
        local duration = 1000 -- 1 second
        transition.to(self, {duration, x=targetX})
    end

    return true
end
```

Have not tested, could be syntax or other errors, but this should give you a good idea of how to proceed (if not put a comment).